# Как организовать фильтрацию элементов по data-атрибутам?

Tags: jquery

Друзья!
Вот кусок html:

```html
<div class="plan" data-bonus="100000">
    <div class="priz" data-price="140000"></div>
    <div class="priz" data-price="100000"></div>
    <div class="priz" data-price="70000"></div>
    <div class="priz" data-price="50000"></div>
    <div class="priz" data-price="30000"></div>
    <div class="priz" data-price="10000"></div>
</div>
<div class="plan" data-bonus="50000">
    <div class="priz" data-price="140000"></div>
    <div class="priz" data-price="100000"></div>
    <div class="priz" data-price="70000"></div>
    <div class="priz" data-price="50000"></div>
    <div class="priz" data-price="30000"></div>
    <div class="priz" data-price="10000"></div>
</div>
```

Нужно сделать так, чтоб при загрузке страницы удалялись элементы div.priz у которых data-price больше чем data-bonus у родителя div.plan

Всю голову сломал, получается либо дикий колхоз в 14232 строк, либо не получается вообще. Уверен, есть решение в 10 строк, но пока ума не приложу. 
С меня 100 р. на телефон за дельный совет! Пишите совет и номер тел. в личку.

Answer (score 1):

Пробегаетесь по всем элементам с классом `priz`, получаете значение `data-bonus` у родительского и значение `data-price` у каждого элемента с классом `priz`, дальше проверяете, если `price` больше `bonus`, то делаете удаление элемента

```js
$(function(){
    $(".priz").each(function(){
        var price = $(this).data("price");
        var bonus = $(this).parent().data("bonus");
        if(price > bonus){
          $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="plan" data-bonus="100000">
    <div class="priz" data-price="140000">140000</div>
    <div class="priz" data-price="100000">100000</div>
    <div class="priz" data-price="70000">70000</div>
    <div class="priz" data-price="50000">50000</div>
    <div class="priz" data-price="30000">30000</div>
    <div class="priz" data-price="10000">10000</div>
</div>
<div class="plan" data-bonus="50000">
    <div class="priz" data-price="140000">140000</div>
    <div class="priz" data-price="100000">100000</div>
    <div class="priz" data-price="70000">70000</div>
    <div class="priz" data-price="50000">50000</div>
    <div class="priz" data-price="30000">30000</div>
    <div class="priz" data-price="10000">10000</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.plan').each(function() {
    var bonus = $(this).data('bonus');
    $('.priz', this).filter(function() {
      return $(this).data('price') < bonus;
    }).css({
      'text-decoration': 'line-through',
      'color': 'gray'
    }); // или hide или что хотите
  })
})
```

```css
.priz:after {
  content: "Цена: " attr(data-price);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="plan" data-bonus="100000">
  <div class="priz" data-price="140000"></div>
  <div class="priz" data-price="100000"></div>
  <div class="priz" data-price="70000"></div>
  <div class="priz" data-price="50000"></div>
  <div class="priz" data-price="30000"></div>
  <div class="priz" data-price="10000"></div>
</div>
<div class="plan" data-bonus="50000">
  <div class="priz" data-price="140000"></div>
  <div class="priz" data-price="100000"></div>
  <div class="priz" data-price="70000"></div>
  <div class="priz" data-price="50000"></div>
  <div class="priz" data-price="30000"></div>
  <div class="priz" data-price="10000"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Пробовал примерно также, вот только сравниваем мы строки, а не значения. Нужно как раз значения

Comment: @АртемПечуляк добавьте `parseInt` к извлекаемому значению атрибута, если вы про это

Comment: @АртемПечуляк `jQuery.data()` возвращает число. http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5 _Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null)_

Comment: Да, точно. Вы правы. Теперь одного не пойму, почему результат такой  <http://юфо-строй-групп.рф/1212.jpg>

Comment: Всё разобрался! Напишите мне в whatsapp, чтоб я мог Вас отблагодарить +7 961 583 08 68

Comment: @АртемПечуляк просто отметьте ответ правильным.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.priz').each(function(i, obj) {
    if ($(this).attr('data-price') > $(this).parent().attr('data-bonus')) 
     $(this).remove();   
});
```